# retrieving data from table, selecting from dropdown, sending to other table PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Yes, I am an compleate noob regarding PHP. But I am trying to make a simple CMS for a school project and i have run into a problem.

I have made a database and 3 tables. One for musicians, one for venues and one for events. The first two i have sucessfully made and i can enter the names and descriptions and stuff in a form and insert it. Now I am trying to make the form for the event table, and I would like there to be, besides text areas for unique data, some dropdown menues where the names of the entries in the other tables can be selected.
So i can call an event a name, write the time and a description and choose from a dropdown the name of the musician, and the venue.

I have cobbled together some code i have found here and there, and I have managed to get the dropdown menues filled with the correct data. But I cannot send it to the event table.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="../cphyoga/insert_event.php" method="post">

<p>
    <label for="event">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="event" id="event">
</p>

<p>
    <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="30">Beskrivelse af begivenheden
    </textarea>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="image">image</label>
    <input type="text" name="image" id="image">
</p>

<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
$dbc = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
?>  
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<?php
$results= mysql_query("SELECT venueid, name FROM venue");
?>

<p>Scene</p>
<select name="venue">
<option value="0">Choose</OPTION>
<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['venueid'].'">'.    $row['name'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select> 
<br>
<?php
$results= mysql_query("SELECT undmusid, name FROM undmus");
?>
<p>Instruktør eller musiker</p>
<select name="undmus">
<option value="0">Choose</OPTION>
<?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['undmusid'].'">'.    $row['name'].'</option>';
    }
?>

</select> 
</form>

<br>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Add">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, if anyone could just help me in the right direction, perhaps you know a tutorial adressing this issue, it would help me a lot.

Comment: had a great effort but i would like to suggest to use ajax because you need to send data to some page once user select some option from dropdown here i give you a link visit an have idea how easily you can ahead this obstacle. [http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/]

Comment: First of all, why 2 `</form>` present at the end ?